# matlab: make script that show plot and ask for input

Tags: matlab, input, plot

I am writing a scipt in matlab that analyses some data I have by allocating it into different categories. I would like to extend my script so that I can manually categorise fragments of data that the script misses, while the script is running.

As it is now, I make a cell array with missed fragments.
I would now like it to do the following, one fragment at a time: (lets say I have 65 fragments)

1. I run the script
2. it shows me a plot with fragment #1
3. it ask me for an input (a number)
4. when I give the input, it show me a plot with fragment #2 and ask for a input.
5. this continues until all 65 fragments have been evaluated
6. the script make a vector with the 65 inputs that the script then continues to use.

Can anybody help me with a couple of hint about which direction I should look to solve this problem?
Thank you very much

Comment: There is good information about using [user input in Matlab in their database.](http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/input.html) Try to implement this and show us your code what you have done. It's hard to help yo with such a general question.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Johannes, you were right, I found a solution using input. It was far less difficult than I thought it would be.

I made a for loop like this:

```
prompt = 'What is the value? ';

cell_array_fragments = (cell array with fragments to check);

number_of_fragments = (number of fragments);

manual_allocate_vector = zeros(number_of_fragments);

for row = 1:number_of_fragments
    if row > 0
        plot(cell_array_fragments{1,row})
        manual_allocate_vector(row) = input(prompt);
    end
end
```